# Making URL out of checkbox values. mvcPattern

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, arrays, checkbox

I'm facing the following problem. I have a overview of users, and I want a possibility to delete multiple users. So if i check user 1 (userid 1) and user 2 (userid 2) they will both delete.

I want to set this in my URL like: `localhost/cms/users/multipledelete/1&2`, so with an &amp.

My delete works allready when i put that url hard in my browser. In my javascript i've the following code:

```
    $('.checkbox').click(function() {
    if($(".checkbox").length == $(".checkbox:checked").length) {
            $("#checkall").prop('checked', this.checked);
        } else {
            $("#checkall").removeAttr("checked");
        }                     
});
```

And in my index i've set up the follow code:

```
<td>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="<?php echo $user->id; ?>"/>
</td>
<td> ....... </td>
```

And beneath my overview my recyclebin where i want to set the url to: multipledelete/1&2

```
              <a href="<?php echo $this->url('zfcadmin/user', array('action'=>'multipledelete', 'id'=>'1&2'));?>">
                   <i class="icon-trash"></i>
              </a>
```

So where 1&2 is, i want the current checked checkboxes. How can i fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use JavaScript to generate the `1&2` string. Something like this (written in jQuery) should work:

```
$('.checkbox:checked').map(function() {
    return this.value;
}).get().join('&');
```

Breaking that down:

- `$('.checkbox:checked')` selects the `checked` checkboxes;
- `.map(function() {
      return this.value;
  })` generates a jQuery object containing an array of their values;
- `.get()` returns that as an actual array
- `.join('&')` returns a string, joining every element of the array with an `&`

I've created a basic [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SEKuY/) so you can see the result of the above.

Now you need to call that when you click on your link (probably best to give it an `id` or `class` so you can select it) so that it's dynamic based on what's checked:

```
$('#anchor-id').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // don't follow the link
    var idString = $('.checkbox:checked').map(function() {
        return this.value;
    }).get().join('&');
    window.location.href = this.href + idString;
});
```

You'd make the `href` attribute of the `<a>` tag the static part, so `localhost/cms/users/multipledelete/`.